# Create delegates like NSURLConnection in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, nsurlconnection

I'm creating my own delegates for a object, but I found some problems...When my delegate is called, the object Client doesn't exist in memory.

The problem is solved if I declare the Client Object like a property of UIViewController, but I think that it's not a good solution.

Why my object is not in memory?

**UPDATED Example code:**

```
//Class UIViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    Client *client = [[Client alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [client login]; //It has two delegates methods (start and finish)
 }  


//In the same class, the delegate methods:    
- (void) start
{
   //DO START STUFF
} 

-(void) finish
{
   // DO FINISH STUFF
}
```

Client.h

```
@interface Client : NSObject <IClient>

@property (nonatomic,assign) id<IClient> _delegate;
-(void)login;
-(id)initWithDelegate:(id<IClient>)delegate;

@end
```

Client.m

```
@implementation Client

@synthesize _delegate;

//Constructor
- (id) initWithDelegate:(id)delegate
{
        self = [super init];
        if(self)
        {
            self._delegate = delegate;
        }
        return self;
}


-(void)login
{
     //Do stuff asynchronously like NSURLConnection
     //Not all code, just a part:
     NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
     delegate:self 
     startImmediately:NO];

     [connection start];

}


//Delegate method of NSURLConnection that login method fires 
//Just implemented one method delegate of NSURLCOnnection for the example

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
        NSLog(@"ERROR");
        [_delegate stop]; //<---CRASH!!!
}

@end
```

IClient.h

```
@protocol IClient <NSObject>

- (void) start;
- (void) finish;

@end
```

When I use `NSURLConnection`, the delegate method pass like param the own `NSURLConnection`, but I have no idea of how I need to implement my delegates like this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

Comment: Which "object doesn't exist in memory"?  The delegate object or the object do the delegation?

Comment: If there is any chance that a single object may receive many events from Client, passing the client instance through delegates will help you to identify who invoked the event.

Comment: The Client object doesn't exit...

Answer (score 1):

> When I use NSURLConnection, the delegate method pass like param the own NSURLConnection

If I understand Google Translate correctly, you want your delegate methods to receive the delegating object itself as an argument. Then why don't you simply implement the logic that way?

In the delegate:

```
- (void)delegateCallback:(DelegatingObject *)obj
{
    // whatever
}
```

In the delegating class/object:

```
[self.delegate delegateCallback:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using ARC, and the client object has no strong references once the viewDidLoad method completes, so it is deallocated. If you were using MRC, you'd be leaking the memory.

The solution *is* to store it as a property or ivar in your view controller, I don't see why you think this is a bad idea. It also gives you the opportunity to cancel the object (if applicable) if your view controller goes off screen or whatever.